# VSE audio playback problem in 2.80

Tags: video-sequence-editor, audio

I have several meta-strips with lots of sound strips in each. I want to edit one of these meta-strips, but when I playback the meta-strip from inside, Blender still plays all sounds from all other meta-strips. 
I decided to mute all meta-strips except from the current, but it did't help. Sounds are playing from all strips, even from muted off. Even if I mute all of the strips, sound is still playing (video behaves as expected, though).
In 2.79 it works just fine.
What happened in 2.80? Is it a bug or I missed some tiny option?

Comment: I'm seeing something very similar in 2.83. Did you ever get to the bottom of this?

Answer (score 0):

Sound like a bug you should report. Remember to mention that it worked correctly in 2.79.
[image]